# MDX - avg function not working as expected when 'where' filter added

Tags: mdx, average

**Issue**

My MDX, below, does not return the average gross profit number I expect.

**MDX**

```
select NON EMPTY {Hierarchize({[New Repeat].[New Repeat].[New]})} ON COLUMNS,
NON EMPTY {Hierarchize({[Measures].[Order Count], [Measures].[Total Gross Profit], [Measures].[Average Gross Profit]})} ON ROWS
from [USAOrders]
where {({{[Voucher Code].[ABC], [Voucher Code].[DEF]}})}
```

Returns:

New Repeat = New

Order Count = 13

Total Gross Profit = 438.03

Average Gross Profit = 24.668

(Average Gross Profit should be 438.03/13 = 33.69)

**How the number is derived**

The SQL derived from this MDX returns 2 rows:

```
new repeat voucher_code | order_count | total_gross_profit | avg_gross_profit    

       "ABC"                    2                23.26      11.63                
       "DEF"                   11               414.77      37.7063636363636
```

So, looking at the numbers it looks like the MDX works out the Average Gross Profit for all specified vouchers by adding up the Average Gross Profit for each individual voucher and then dividing by the number rows of different vouchers (in this case 2):

e.g. (11.63 + 37.7063636363636)/2 = 24.668

Whereas, in order to get the correct number, it should add up the values in Total Gross Profit and divide by the number of rows from the original data:

e.g. (23.26 + 414.77)/13 = 33.69

(Within the cube, Total and Average Gross Profit are measures defined using the sum and avg functions on the gross profit measure/column).

Is there a way to resolve the issue to get the correct number?

Many thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Your MDX is very simple. It is just pulling numbers from the cube, and not adjusting them in any way. If there is an error, it must be in the agregation method or measure calculations in the OLAP cube.

I believe you want to use the `SOLVE_ORDER` command to instruct the cube to perform the calculations to get total_gross_profit first, and then do the averaging calculation. Sorry I can't give you the exact syntax to just plug in; you'll have to read the documentation.